# How to save DIV content to HTML file using AJAX/JQuery/PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am struggling with getting this code to work. My intention is to be able to save the contents of a div to an html file, so that I can recall it later...
It works partially, in that if I change `$data=$_POST['id']` to `$data=$_POST['memory']` in `readInput.php` it will indeed save any text I enter into the input named 'memory' to an html file, and will correctly save the file with whatever name I give it. Where it fails is if I try to grab the data of DIV `'readDiv'` and its contents `$data=$_POST['id'];` it will save a blank html page, with whatever name I gave it... Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>readInput</title>
<meta name="description" content="HTML5 web page">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML5">
<meta name="author" content="You">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link href="jquery-ui.htm" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.htm"></script>
 <script name="saveMemory" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#saveMemory').click(function() {
     //e.preventDefault();
       var content = $('#readDiv').html(); // orig
        //var content = document.getElementById('readDiv').value; // test
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'readInput.php',
                  data: {id: content}
                  //dataType: "html" // test
                  });
          });
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.readWrite.writeInput.focus();"><!--form name.input name.focus!-->
    <div id="formContainer" style="display:block">
          <form name="readWrite" action="readInput.php" method="POST">
             <input name="memory" placeholder="...enter text here..." type="text">
             <input name="readMemory" id="readMemory" class="readMemory" placeholder="...read..." type="text">

           <input id="writeInput" name="writeInput" class="writeInput" placeholder="...write..." type="text">       
           <input class="saveMemory" id="saveMemory" name="saveMemory" value="...saveMemory..." type="submit">

          </form></div>
          <div name="readDiv" id="readDiv" class="readDiv">
          <div id="writeDiv" class="writeDiv" title="writeDiv">test text
          <div id="topDropbox" class="topDropbox" title="topDropbox">
    <img src="car.jpg">
    </div></div></div>
    </body></html>
```

`readInput.php`:

```
     <?php
 $writeInput = $_POST['writeInput'];
 $data = $_POST['id'];

 $fileName = ("memories/$writeInput.html");
 $fileHandle = fopen($fileName, 'w+') or die("Cannot open file");
 fwrite($fileHandle, $data);
 fclose($fileHandle);
 echo($fileName);
 echo($data);
 ?>
```

It probably looks like a horrible hack job to you pros because I have tried so many bits of code, and I am sure I am just missing something silly, but I am at a loss...thank you anyone for any help!

Comment: you are only sending one parameter to php `id`. There is no `writeInput` property in the data object. Suggest you get the ajax working by simply outputting post params before worrying about file writing

Comment: The writeInput seems to work ok, in that it will allow me to type in any name in the '...write...' input field, and then clicking save it does create and save a new file in the proper place, the html file is just empty, with no readDiv contents...unless you mean I am missing something else :)

Comment: yes you are, you aren't preventing default submit of form, so browser is likely submitting the `writeinput` field through browser default process (then reloading the page). Can return false from clcik handler for that, but then you need to update data object for ajax also so that all data expected is sent

Comment: Hmm ok so if I uncomment the e.preventDefault is that proper? Im not sure how to update such data, sorry I am obviously new at this

Comment: Yes uncomment the `e.preventDefault()` it's there to prevent the form from doing it's default action. Submit data. You want to submit the date via AJAX. That is going to introduce a new problem now `$_POST['writeInput'];` will be undefined.

Comment: you need `e` as an argument first to be able to use `e.preventDefault()`, then look at the object passed to `data`. It needs to have `writeinput` property and value also

Comment: Thank you, I have updated as you suggested...getting closer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This update should do the trick:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#saveMemory').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
       var content = $('#readDiv').html(); // orig
        //var content = document.getElementById('readDiv').value; // test
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'readInput.php',
                  data: {id: content, writeInput : $('#writeInput').val()}
                  //dataType: "html" // test
                  }).done(
                        function( data ){
                            $('#result).html( data);
                        }
                  );
          });
     });
```

Changes:

1. Added `e` to the click function. It provides the function with a reference to the event object.
2. Uncommented `e.preventDefault()` so the form won't execute breaking the ajax call.
3. Added `writeInput` to the post data.
4. Added a callback (`.done`). When the request is finished this function will execute writing the `responseData` into `writeDiv`

Add the following div directly in the body tag.

```
<div id="result" style="background-color: #f4f4f4;width:100%;height:300px;overflow: auto"></div>
```

Comment: Very cool thank you... writeInput works like this,but its like the readDiv data is not getting properly posted or something because the html file ends up only containing the echo fileName from php, EX: 'memories/`$writeInput`.html'

Comment: @Jay is there even html in your `readDiv`. From the posted code I couldn't make up how it's filled? What I'm saying readDiv is empty, so it posts empty data. Shouldn't the content be `readMemory` or `memory`?

Comment: Well I have the car.jpg and some test text in the readDiv which i assume should get posted/saved, and the writeDiv is inside of readDiv, so all that should get copied? I hope hehe

Comment: @Jay true, overlooked

Comment: yeah its like im screwing up on getting the readDiv to get posted as data or something

Comment: @Jay Strange thing. On my server the content is submitted just fine.

Comment: Hmm you actually got this to work on yours? Hmm maybe I have something wrong on my end...just not sure where! Hey thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Ok I have tested, same.. when i click save, the page actually redirects to readInputphp with the echo of filename only, is it supposed to do that or stay on page and insert data into result div?

Comment: HEY thanks! I got it working - it was of course a file permission problem on my end (Ubuntu newbie), but without your help with the other things (writeInput very helpful) and such I would not have found it - thank you!